# Pasar HashMap a JList

Tags: java

Quiero pasar los datos de jugadores a una lista desde la que poder realizar acciones como darlos de baja, etc(en un jframe). Es un juego de poker, los jugadores tienen dni, nombre, etc.

Mi idea es ejecutar el siguiente método en el main del jFrame:

```
public void getJugadores() {
    //Cargo el hashmap serializado de jugadores:
    HashMap<String, Jugador> jugadores = null;
    jugadores = ca.cargaHashMap(jugadores);

    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    ArrayList<Jugador> jugadores_arr = new ArrayList<Jugador>(jugadores.values());

    for (int i = 0; i < jugadores_arr.size(); i++) {
        listModel.addElement(jugadores_arr.get(i).toString());
    }
    lista_jugadores.setModel(listModel);

}
```

Como véis he pasado un hashmap serializado a un array (jugadores_arr), y he intentado usar un defaultlistmodel para cargar los datos de jugadores y después añadirlos a la jlist. El problema es que al ejecutar me sale esto:
[image: Error]

Y no sé cómo solucionarlo. Entiendo que el error es un puntero a algo vacío, pero no sé cómo solucionarlo ni dónde está el error.

¿Estoy realizándolo de la forma correcta? ¿Hay una forma más sencilla ó correcta de pasar un hashmap a un jlist? ¿Qué está fallando?

Comment: Por que utilizas tantos objetos para almacenar los jugadores, No te compliques, te recomiendo que solo utilices uno ya sea el ArrayList que es mas dinamico y facil de usar

Comment: y donde te sale el error?